# Unable to login into Stack Exchange Data Explorer

Tags: bug, status-completed, data-explorer, stack-exchange-openid

It might be related to the [recent SEDE outage](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344277/sede-is-offline) but I'm unable to login to SEDE via Stack Exchange Open ID. When clicking the 'Log in using Stack Exchange' button, I get an error message

> No OpenID endpoint found.

[image]

Comment: Login using Google works :)

Comment: Hmm, not sure why this isn't working, we'll take a look

Comment: I get a different error now: *Web request to 'https://openid.stackexchange.com/openid/provider' failed.*

Comment: Hey all, there’s *something* wrong with the redundant app setup in NY to get things working for you all, but I can’t see what it is after looking for a bit tonight. Apologies it’ll likely be another day while we either get CO up or fix NY. This week has just kicked our butts and between hardware failure and gravity-related accidents, we’re not quite back to 100% yet. Thanks for bearing with us, we’ll get it all back working as soon as possible.

Comment: *"gravity-related accidents"* Well, now my interest is piqued...

Comment: @CodyGray https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1233777372098367488

Comment: @CodyGray Someone might have [fallen down the stairs](https://twitter.com/Nick_Craver/status/1233777372098367488) - it's been a really rough week.

Comment: @NickCraver Thank you! I guess NY refers to a server cluster located in New York. What does CO refer to?

Comment: @WXJ96163 Colorado: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_U.S._state_abbreviations

Comment: @Glorfindel can you please test logging in now?

Comment: @Taryn works like a charm, TYVM

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Okay sooooooo this wasn't related to the outage or the move or the redundancy or any of that. It was only close in timing.

You know how we said [we were going to turn off TLS 1.0 and 1.1](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/343302/tls-1-0-and-tls-1-1-removal-for-stack-exchange-services)? Whelp, that went live on our load balancers on February 25th (6 days ago). It turns out SEDE was still doing this because it had:

```xml
<httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
```

This little switch [controls a lot of things](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.5-4.7), including [what the default TLS protocols to use are](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/migration-guide/retargeting/4.5-4.7#default-value-of-servicepointmanagersecurityprotocol-is-securityprotocoltypesystemdefault). It wasn't allowing TLS 1.2. This was [just fixed for everyone using SEDE](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.DataExplorer/pull/96) by re-targeting to .NET 4.7.