# search results dropped my expected answer that contains every single words I entered

Tags: support, search

**Note**: I am not asking the discussion post about a specific question. I've already got that post. I am asking a general search skill.

I encountered "No OpenID endpoint found" error just now. So, I searched for the following keywords

> Stack Exchange data No OpenID endpoint found

and then I got this result

[image]

which is NOT my intended answer.

Actually, another post ([Unable to login into Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/344386/714660)) contains every single words I searched, which is my expected answer.

## question

what keywords should I use to find the expected answer

Comment: Consider to add additional information to add into your already existing question, rather than asking a new one please.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [login data.stackexchange encounter "No OpenID endpoint found" error](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/344410/login-data-stackexchange-encounter-no-openid-endpoint-found-error)

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Thanks. I am not asking the discussion post about a specific question. I've already got that post. I am asking a general search skill.

Comment: You should read the advanced search tips to learn how to search for a phrase exactly https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching You are searching for two separate phrases here and must format your search as such. Doing it correctly, gives the expected result https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22Stack+Exchange+data%22+%22No+OpenID+endpoint+found%22 Nowhere does the linked post contain "Stack Exchange data No OpenID endpoint found" as a single line.

Comment: @MarkKirby: that's not the issue here, they were not searching for a phrase (using quotes around the search terms), they were searching *for keywords*. When you remove the word `data` the post is found. The issue is that words in the *title* don't seem to be taken into account.

Comment: @MarkKirby: e.g. replacing the word `data` with `sede` (which *does* appear in the question body) produces [just two hits with the sought-after post listed first](https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=stack+exchange+sede+No+OpenID+endpoint+found).

Comment: Again, read the advanced search tips. If you want to search a title use "title: ". https://meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=title%3A++Stack+Exchange+data++%22No+OpenID+endpoint+found%22 the search is a bit awkward to use but there is no issue here, you are just using it wrong. Alternatively just use Google, if you expect the site search to work like Google, you will have a bad time.

Comment: @MarkKirby: when searching for keywords it is perfectly natural to combine fields. This is a basic keyword query, the title text is part of the base text.

Comment: @MarkKirby: to state that someone is "using search wrong" because they didn't realise that the title text is not part of the keyword search index is *definitely* the wrong response here. Just because the search configuration is incorrectly disregarding a text field present on all questions *and* there is a search option to restrict search to words found in the title doesn't mean the OP used search wrong. It means that *search is incorrectly configured*.

Comment: @MarkKirby: and last, but not least: yes, Google does a (much) better job of mapping search query to results. They have dedicated engineers working on query tuning. That doesn't mean we need to give up on improving the search engine here, not when this is, in my own experience with elastic search, to include words from the title in the keyword index is *simply a configuration choice*.

Comment: @MartijnPieters No, the fact the OP did not format the search correctly does mean they were using it wrong (not necessarily their fault but still true). When formatted correctly, it gives the expected results, so the mistake is user error. I agree that the search should be improved but that is not what this question is about, Op asked for "what keywords should I use to find the expected answer" and I have given two versions they can use to get the correct results and the reason that their search did not give that result is user error.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The word `data` only appears in that question's title. If you remove it from the search, the post in question shows up:

[image]

When you add `sede` to the search, a word that does appear in the body, you only have two hits:

[image]

What this means is that words in the title appear to be *ignored* when searching. That's surprising, and may well be a bug. A basic keyword-only search (not using a `title:` or other advanced query search parameter) should not exclude words from the question title.

Comment: Thank you. The keywords entered without any modifier syntax is to only match `posts.Body`, right?

Comment: @WXJ96163 That’s what it looks like, yes.